# Dealing with Leap Seconds Correctly

Tags: java, time, unix-timestamp, ntp, leap-second

Before and during a leap second, it appears that calling `new Date()` will return 23:59:59 twice (once before the leap second, and once during the leap second), rather than 23:59:59, and 23:59:60.

Is there a way (short of implementing an NTP client within the application, or checking for the clock to go backwards or repeat itself) to determine whether or not a given second is a leap second or not, so as to correctly present 23:59:60 to the user?

For that matter, do host operating systems have any hooks to determine whether or not it is pre or post leap second?

Comment: Java SE 8 clearly defines leap second behavior here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html

Comment: I don't think a technique such as the *leap smear* would qualify as correct representation of a leap second but it's definitely a valid way to handle leap seconds, at least in a server/database context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751115/leap-second-handling-in-database/19756183#19756183

Answer (score 8):

Let's look into the source code of `java.util.Date`:

```
public Date() {
    this(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

So the question can be read as:

Will `System.currentTimeMillis()` yield the leap second value 60 or even 61 (as the spec pretends)?

The answer is in strict sense: It depends on the underlying operating system. But fact is: All well known operating systems like Windows, Linux, Apple, Android are ignorant towards leap seconds. Instead These operating systems make any clock manipulations at any time (setting back etc., synchronizing with NTP-server...). **So you will not observe a leap second using the `Date`-API.** By the way, the value 61 is impossible because UTC-standard mandates that UTC will never deviate from UT1 by more than 0.9 secs with the consequence that a double leap second will not be inserted.

The origin of "61" is just a gross misunderstanding from early POSIX-specifications (where this mistake has been corrected now). Unfortunately the old Java-spec has not yet been corrected causing misunderstandings until now.

**About Java-8:**

Yes, the so-called "Java Time-Scale" is formally specified as UTC-SLS - based on an expired proposal whose intent was rather directed towards internal implementations of NTP-servers. No implementation of UTC-SLS exist in real world. Even **Java-8 does not implement UTC-SLS**. Two facts prove this statement:

- Java-8 does not contain a leap second table (which would be the foundation of any UTC-SLS-implementation). The Threeten-project had originally hold such one but it was removed (now also [removed from the backport](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp/issues/30)).
- The conversion from `java.util.Date` to `Instant` is just 1:1 (see source code - leaving aside the different precision millis vs. nanos). Note that `java.util.Date` is not mentioned in the API of `Instant` with respect to the so-called "Java Time scale".

> The Java time-scale is used for all date-time classes. This includes
>   Instant, LocalDate, LocalTime, OffsetDateTime, ZonedDateTime and
>   Duration.

Furthermore: The origin of `java.util.Date` is from 1995 (when Java was invented) but UTC-SLS was proposed several years later.

So what is left in Java-8 as leap second support? Empty words in spec causing a lot of confusion, nothing else.

**What can you do else?** Within the scope of JDK simply nothing. What you need is an external 3rd-party library with built-in leap second data. An example is my library Time4J - see this [article](http://www.dzone.com/articles/how-watch-next-coming-leap). Another option might be the library Threeten-Extra with its class [UTCInstant](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/scale/UtcInstant.html). But I have not tested its conversion to `java.util.Date` (seems to be suspect?).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Java8 documentation for the Date class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), calling Date during the leap second will/did correctly return :60 or :61.

So you don't need to do anything.

How it does that is a bit of mystery though, since the underlying [Instant class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) spreads the leap second out over the last 1000 seconds of the day - so each of those last seconds will actually be 1.001 seconds long - and your application wont know whether it's in the leap second or not.

Comment: The `java.time.Instant` class does *not* underlie the `java.util.Date`, as far as I know. Notice the package names. The former is from the brand-new (as of Java 8) java.time framework. The latter is very old, from the first version of Java. Date has a couple of convenience conversion methods for Instant, but their code bases are entirely separate.